# Specifying the x-axis when importing a csv with pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas, matplotlib, timeserieschart

I am not sure why but the data I have imported from my csv files is all plotted on the y-axis. This is what I want in this case, but I would like to know how to import x-axis data from a csv file.

It doesn't seem to let me import dates as strings but anyhow in most cases I just want the year along the x-axis. E.g 2006, 2007...2016, or maybe with the month as well as year. How could I go about do this by amending the following code? I have attached a photo of the plot after the code.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import style

style.use('bmh')

df = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Paul/Desktop/pandas datasets/belfast_centre.csv")
df2 = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Paul/Desktop/pandasdatasets/cardiff_centre.csv")

ozone_subset = df.iloc[:, 2,]  
ozone_subset2 = df2.iloc[:, 2]

ozone_subset.plot(color="green", linewidth=2, linestyle="-")
ozone_subset2.plot(color="azure", linewidth=2, linestyle="-")

plt.title('Nitrogen oxides - monthly averages',fontsize = 'large',fontname='Arial',)
plt.ylabel('NOx ugm-3',fontname='Arial',fontsize = 'medium')
plt.xlabel('Month number',fontname='Arial',fontsize = 'medium')
plt.legend(loc='upper right', fontsize = 'small')
plt.show()
```

Monthly time series plot from the above code

[image]

Comment: Could you edit the question to include a few lines from each of your CSV files?

Comment: You have to do something like `df.set_index()`, to make that the x-axis

Comment: you can specify which columns go where with `x` and `y` parameters in your call `ozone_df.plot`